# Kubernetes not creating ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I'm trying to set up my Kubernetes services as being external by using type: LoadBalancer on AWS. After I created my service using kubectl I can see the change but no ELB is created, not even async. Any hints on what could cause this? The pod I'm trying to expose is running a Docker image which exposes a web-server on port 8001.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  labels:
    name:  my-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
  - port: 8001
  selector:
    name:  my-service
```

Comment: Did you wait 2-4 minutes?

Comment: it actually worked after 10 minutes or something...really strange. If you post your comment as an answer I'd be glad to accept it :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021181/google-container-engine-kubernetes-is-not-exposing-external-ip-after-creating-c/35022724#35022724 :-)

Answer (score 0):

This was answered by Jan Garaj in [Google Container Engine: Kubernetes is not exposing external IP after creating container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021181/google-container-engine-kubernetes-is-not-exposing-external-ip-after-creating-c) regarding a GCE deployment and the answer for AWS is the same: you need to wait a few minutes for the reconciler to kick in, notice that the ELB should be created, talk to the AWS APIs and create it for you.